# Convert reinterpret_cast from C++ to Python

Tags: python, c++, casting, reinterpret-cast

I have this piece of code in C++ that I want to convert to Python:

```
int main() {
    char buf[21] = "211000026850KBAALHAA";
    std::cout << reinterpret_cast<const uint32_t*>(buf+12) << "\n";
    const uint32_t *num = reinterpret_cast<const uint32_t*>(buf+12);
    std::cout << num[0] << " " << num[1] << "\n";
}
```

which prints `1094795851 1094797388`. I want to write a similar function to have input of `KBAALHAA` and output of `1094795851 1094797388`. I cannot seem to find the equivalent of reinterpret_cast function in Python.

Comment: Why would you need that? Even in contemporary C++ you should sparsely need pointers at all, let alone `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: That's most probably a so-called XY problem. Look up that term. Also, think about what the C++ code does and how it works, it should be easy to reproduce in Python.

Comment: you cannot translate 1:1 from C++ to python. You can write a equivalent program in python that produces same output for same input, but it probably wouldn't use anything like `reinterpret_cast` (even in C++ this approach is questionable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `unpack_from` function from the `struct` module is perfect for this.

https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/struct.html#struct.unpack_from

> Unpack from *buffer* starting at position *offset*, according to the *format* string format. The result is a tuple even if it contains exactly one item. The buffer’s size in bytes, starting at position *offset*, must be at least the size required by the format, as reflected by calcsize().

The format string used here is `II`. `I` being an 4-byte unsigned int.

```py
import struct

string = b"211000026850KBAALHAA"
num = struct.unpack_from("II", string, 12)
print(num[0], num[1])
```

Output:

```
1094795851 1094797388
```